# How we can use facebook AppEventsLogger add to cart event in react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-fbsdk

I am trying to implement facebook SDK to track Add to cart event in my application but it was not working here is my code

First, I import facebook SDK in my application react-native-fbsdk which was installed successfully and login function are working well.

Now in product screen, I import facebook AppEventsLogger and AppEventsConstants from SDK

```
const FBSDK = require('react-native-fbsdk');
const {
    AppEventsLogger,
    AppEventsConstants
} = FBSDK;
```

And when user add product successfully to its carts i need to track this event in log, I try below code but it was not working

```
var params = {};
params[AppEventsConstants.CONTENT] = "Sample Product 1";
params[AppEventsConstants.CONTENT_ID] = "1";
params[AppEventsConstants.CONTENT_TYPE] = "Product";
params[AppEventsConstants.CURRENCY] = "INR";

AppEventsLogger.logEvent(AppEventsConstants.EVENT_NAME_ADDED_TO_WISHLIST, 40, params)
```

Above code give me an undefined error. Please help me how to implement this.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, react-native-fbsdk doesn't provide constants of standard event names and parameter names. After some research, I found actual names are listed in Marketing API documentation (why not App Events?).

I don't know if it is the right place, but you can refer to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/app-event-api/ for actual standard event names and parameter names. At least it worked in my case. Here's my Add to Cart event code:

```
function logAddToCart(totalPrice, contentType, contentId, currency) {
    const params = {
        'fb_content_type': contentType,
        'fb_content_id': contentId,
        'fb_currency': currency
    };
    AppEventsLogger.logEvent('fb_mobile_add_to_cart', totalPrice, params);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

u can read from the docs react-native-fbsdk
https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk/blob/17af77b48ad6ea62fa3c0f552cd8f6a699ef6a64/src/FBAppEventsLogger.js#L92

and u can find constant from this
https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/facebook-core/src/main/java/com/facebook/appevents/AppEventsConstants.java#L33-L312

```
// helpers

import { AppEventsLogger } from 'react-native-fbsdk'

export const FB_ADDED_TO_CART = 'fb_mobile_add_to_cart'
export async function logAdsEvent(eventName, ...args) {
  let valueToSum = 0
  if (typeof args[0] === 'number') {
    valueToSum = args.shift()
  }
  let parameters = null
  if (typeof args[0] === 'object') {
    parameters = toSnakeCase(args[0])
  }

  AppEventsLogger.logEvent(eventName, valueToSum, parameters)

}
```

implementation

```
import helpers

 logAdsEvent(FB_ADDED_TO_CART, result.stores[0].subTotal || 0, {
          fbContent: JSON.stringify(result.stores[0]),
          fbCurrency: 'IDR'
        })
```